# why confidence interval of 100 does not cover full data?

Tags: python, statistics, seaborn

I have this dataframe `df1` with the following `.head()`

```
                     month  temp
date                            
2023-01-01 01:00:00      1  11.0
2023-01-01 02:00:00      1  11.0
2023-01-01 03:00:00      1  10.0
2023-01-01 04:00:00      1  10.0
2023-01-01 05:00:00      1  10.0
```

I tried to plot data using seaborn line, and wanted to see the entire range of data (min,max,mean) on graph.

So I assumed that by using `month` as x-axis and `temp` as y-axis and setting confidence interval to `ci=100` it will cover the entire data, and show the needed information

```
sns.lineplot(data=df,x='month',y='temp',errorbar=('ci', 100),ax=ax[0])
```

But it did not!

It resulted with a bound that is thinner than the max/min range, as shown below:
[image: comparison between min/max and ci=100]

Any idea what I did/assumed wrong?

Comment: [Perhaps useful](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/error_bars).

Answer (score 1):

Apparently I should have used 'pi' instead of 'ci':

[image]

But it is still strange why ci does not have same effect.